# Session is not updated after set for the first time in Laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-10

currently i'm developing a web app on Laravel 10.

I have an issue where session is not updated after the session is set/defined for the first time .

route.php

```
Route::get('Registration', [MySecondController::class, 'create'])
        ->name('register');
Route::get('Registration/DetailPersonal', [MySecondController::class, 'CreateDetailPersonal']);
});
```

Controller that extends BaseController

```
function __construct()
{
    Session::put('sessionTokens', "12345");
    print_r(Session::get('sessionTokens')); //show 12345
}
```

MySecondController that extends Controller

```
class MySecondController extends Controller{
    public function CreateDetailPersonal(): View
    {
        $this->middleware("guest");
        
        print_r(session("sessionTokens")); //show 12345
        return view('auth.registerpersonalatt');
    }
}
```

After i change the session `session::set('sessionTokens','678910');` in Constructor

Print the Session in MySecondController, it shows **12345** not **678910**

I set my `session_driver` to `file`

Is there any reason why it's happening? is there something i miss ?

Thanks Before

**EDIT**

Try to set session in second controller and access it in third controller  it's working .  It's not working only when it sets in constructor of Controller that extends BaseController

Answer (score 0):

The constructor is called before the middleware `guest` has been applied, so the session may be unavailable at that time. you can use the 'booted' method of your controller, which is called after the middleware has been applied and before the route method is executed

```
public function booted()
{
    session(['sessionTokens' => '12345']);
}
```

Comment: yup, the **sessiontokens** will update frequently in certain minutes after hit rest API. In this case, i just want to make sure that **sessiontokens** will updated even it has been set

Comment: It seems contructor method is called before the guest middleware. So the session value might not have been updated. You can try boot() instead of constructor.

Comment: I try to create boot function. But boot method isn't called. try to dd("test") but it's not showing on screen

Comment: try with booted() method. check updated answer